# Why does the FDM give a correct solution to a PDE with a discontinuous initial condition?

Tags: finite-difference, hyperbolic-pde, wave-propagation

I was solving the dimensionless wave equation:

$$ u_{xx} = u_{tt} \tag 1$$

with the initial conditions:

$$ u(x,0) = 0 \tag 2 $$

$$ u_t(x=0,0) = v_0 \tag 2 $$
$$ u_t(x>0,0) = 0 \tag 3 $$

and the boundary conditions:

$$ u(1,t) = 0 \tag 4 $$
$$ mu_{tt}(0, t) + u_x(0, t) = 0 \Leftrightarrow mu_{xx}(0, t) + u_x(0, t) = 0 \tag 5$$

This represents the mathematical model of an elastic rod subjected to a rigid body impact.
The constant $m$ is the mass ratio of the rigid body and elastic rod, and $v_0$ is the velocity of the rigid body at the initial time of impact. The function $u$ is the longitudinal displacement.

I managed to solve this model up to $t_{max} = 2$. The solution for $t \in [0, 1]$ is:

$$ u(x,t) = mv_0  \Bigg( e^{ {t-x}\over m } - 1 \Bigg) \ \mathrm{if} \ t \geq x \tag 6$$
$$ u(x,t) = 0 \ \mathrm{if} \ t \leq x \tag 7$$

For $t \in [1, 2]$, the solution is:

$$ u(x,t) = mv_0  \Bigg( e^{ {t-x}\over m } - e^{ {t+x-2}\over m } \Bigg) \ \mathrm{if} \ t \geq x - 2 \tag 8$$
$$ u(x,t) = mv_0  \Bigg( e^{ {t-x}\over m } - 1 \Bigg) \ \mathrm{if} \ t \leq x - 2 \tag 9$$

The problem is that the solution is piecewise-defined. The expression changes each time the wave hits a boundary. So using an analytical solution to analyze the wave propagation is not very practical if the impact duration is long enough to have a lot of wave reflections. So I decided to simulate this process using the finite difference method.

To my surprise, the numerical solution and the analytical solution match perfectly, as shown in the graphs below:

[image: Picture]

Note that the ratio of the time step and spatial step is not equal to one (the so-called magic CFL number). It is equal to $0.67$.

Here is what I don't understand. I have a discontinuous initial condition $(2)$, $(3)$. The group velocity and phase velocity are not equal. I was expecting a significant numerical dispersion at the wavefront. However, that did not happen. My question is, why?

In the past, I was solving a similar problem and had an issue with significant numerical dispersion. I even made a post about it [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/43433/can-this-finite-difference-dispersion-be-eliminated-somehow). Why is it that this time the numerical dispersion is not significant enough to be visible when plotting the solution? Could this be only because my solution is continuous even though it is not smooth (so it's not the smoothness of the solution, but the continuity of it that affects numerical dispersion)?

**Note:** I will be making edits suggested by comments.

**EDIT 1:**

I used the central difference approximation of second-order accuracy:

$$u_{tt} = {U_{i+1,j} - 2U_{i,j} + U_{i-1,j}\over \Delta t^2} \tag {10}$$
$$u_{xx} = {U_{i,j+1} - 2U_{i,j} + U_{i,j-1} \over \Delta x^2} \tag {11}$$

**EDIT 2:**

I calculated analytically and numerically the partial time derivative of displacement. The numerical partial derivative was calculated using the central difference approximation. I came across something that might give a clue to finding the answer to my question. Namely, if the CFL number is equal to one, there is a good match between the solutions (as shown in the two pictures below):

[image: Picture_1]
[image: Picture_2]

However, after changing the CFL number to $0.67$, the displacement wave function still did not deviate noticeably, but the time derivative of it did. Especially at the wavefront (as shown in the picture below). The oscillations are taking place:

[image: Picture_3]
[image: Picture_4]

**EDIT 3:**

Because the graphs seem more like straight lines than exponential functions (which is visually misleading), I added a code snippet showing how I calculated the analytical solution in Matlab. Indeed, the graphs are exponential functions, not linear ones.

```
%% Analytical solution

u   = zeros(nx, not);
u_t = zeros(nx, not);

u_t(1, 1) = v_0;

if t_max == 2

    for i = 1 : (nt + 1) / 2

        for j = 1 : nx
    
            if t(i) > x(j)
            
                u(j, i)   = v_0 * m * (exp( (t(i) - x(j)) / m ) - 1);
            
                u_t(j, i) = v_0 * exp( (t(i) - x(j)) / m );

            end
        end
    end

    for i = ( (nt + 1) / 2) + 1 : not

        for j = 1 : nx

            if t(i) > (2 - x(j))

              u(j, i)   = v_0 * m * (                        ...
                          exp( ( t(i) - (x(j)    ) ) / m ) - ...
                          exp( ( t(i) + (x(j) - 2) ) / m )   ...
                          );
                
              u_t(j, i) = v_0 * (                            ...
                          exp( ( t(i) - (x(j)    ) ) / m ) - ...
                          exp( ( t(i) + (x(j) - 2) ) / m )   ...
                          );
        
            else
            
                u(j, i)   = v_0 * m * (exp( (t(i) - x(j)) / m ) - 1);
            
                u_t(j, i) = v_0 * exp( (t(i) - x(j)) / m );
            
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Also, I posted a code snippet below showing how I use finite differences to calculate the wave functions.

```
%% Numerical functions

U   = zeros(nx, nt);
U_t = zeros(nx, nt);

%% Initial condition implementation

U(1, 2)   = dt * v_0;
U_t(1, 1) = v_0;

%% Finite difference loop

j = 2 : nx - 1;

for i = 2 : nt - 1

    g = ( 4 * m * U(1, i) - (2 * m + dx) * U(1 + 1, i) ) / (2 * m - dx); % Ghost node

    U(1, i + 1) = -U(1, i - 1) + 2 * U(1, i) + (dt^2 / dx^2) * ( U(1 + 1, i) - 2 * U(1, i) + g );      

    U(j, i + 1) = -U(j, i - 1) + 2 * U(j, i) + (dt^2 / dx^2) * ( U(j + 1, i) - 2 * U(j, i) + U(j - 1, i) );   

    U_t(:, i) = ( U(:, i + 1) - U(:, i - 1) ) / (2 * dt);
end

%% Calculate time derivative at last time step

UU = zeros(nx, 1);

i = nt;

g = ( 4 * m * U(1, i) - (2 * m + dx) * U(1 + 1, i) ) / (2 * m - dx);

UU(1) = -U(1, i - 1) + 2 * U(1, i) + (dt^2 / dx^2) * ( U(1 + 1, i) - 2 * U(1, i) + g );      

UU(j) = -U(j, i - 1) + 2 * U(j, i) + (dt^2 / dx^2) * ( U(j + 1, i) - 2 * U(j, i) + U(j - 1, i) ); 

U_t(:, i) = ( UU - U(:, i - 1) ) / (2 * dt);
```

**EDIT 4:** Below I added the error graphs suggested in the comment section. I calculated the error as the analytical solution minus the numerical solution ($Err = u - U$). In the titles are the time-space ratio, as well as the time moments. When the time-space ratio is one, nu dispersion is noticed, while in the other case, the dispersion is noticeable but of small magnitude.

[image: Err0]
[image: Err1]

Comment: You haven't said what numerical scheme you used and that could make a huge difference. To address at least one part of your question, there's a big difference between having a 0th-order and 1st-order time derivative being discontinuous.

Comment: I edited my answer. It was the 5-point central difference stencil. Also, I agree with you on the derivative part. However, if $u_t$ is discontinuous, then also $u_{tt}$ and $u_{xx}$ should be discontinuous. I know I am integrating twice in time, but I am also differentiating twice in space which I am not sure why gives a good result. I don't know why differentiating twice in space doesn't produce a problem.

Comment: Having made more than my fair share of mistakes, could you check if you are indeed plotting the numerical and analytical solution? Or perhaps, are you plotting the analytical solution twice?

Comment: Checked it. Indeed, plotting numerical and analytical solution.

Comment: Did you check convergence, i.e., the error in infinity norm when increasing spatial resolution / drecrease time step? Does that match your expectations?

Comment: I think you mean the $L_2$ norm, right? The energy-summation by parts can tell me the stability condition, but I am not sure how it can show me that there will be no dispersion. If you actually do mean the infinity norm, I do not know how can I do that (or how it would help me understand this phenomenon). Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @NikolaRistic I think you should visualize the derivative of your solution. In particular, it is consistent with your claim of using discontinuous initial conditions. Otherwise you would compare apples with oranges.

Comment: Your exact solution is exponential, but the plots look like (piecewise) linear in x?

Comment: @ConvexHull Thank you for the good suggestion. It did give an interesting result. I posted it in the edit of my question.

Comment: @timur It just seems like that, but it really is exponential. I posted a snippet showing that I really do calculate the function using exponentials.

Comment: @NikolaRistic: Thanks! Can you please explain how you implemented the boundary condition (5) numerically?

Comment: @timur Ofcourse. I calculated the ghost node the following way. From $(5)$ I first I wrote $$mu_{xx}+u_x = m(U_{i,j+1} + U_{i,j-1} - 2 U_{i,j})/ \Delta x^2 + (U_{i,j+1} - U_{i,j-1}) / (2 \Delta x)=0 \ (\mathrm{Eq} \ 1)$$.  

The ghost node is $g=U_{i,j-1}$, where the index $j$ is equal to one since Matlab indexing starts from one. From $(\mathrm{Eq}\ 1)$ I simply wrote $U_{i,j-1}$ in terms of $U_{i,j}$ and $U_{i,j+1}$ and that's how I implemented the boundary condition $(5)$.

Comment: Did you consieder doing a fourier analysis on your solution? Based on the accepted answer to the previous question you linked, I would guess the reason is that you have a significantly lower amount of energy in the high frequency components of your solution, this time. This would explain why you don't see oscillations, despite your FD scheme is dispersive. If I find some time I'll write down a complete answer to this post.

Comment: Indeed, let's take a triangle wave as a representative of a non smooth, yet continuous, function. The amplitude of its components drops proportionally to the inverse of the square of the frequency. Instead, taking a square wave as representative of a discontinuous function, you'll notice that the amplitude of the components drops as the inverse of the frequency (i.e. significantly slower than the triangle wave components).

Comment: I actually never did a Fourier transformation of a function with two variables. I need to check first how to do it. However, I am guessing it is just taking the Fourier transform with respect to one variable and then once more with respect to the second variable. Hopefully, then I just need to do a surface plot of circular frequency and  wave numbers with respect to the magnitude of the resultant complex function. Once I do it, I will write it in the answer. Though, if you manage also to do it and write it in the answer, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: I don't think the decay rate of Fourier modes is enough to explain this dramatic difference. As Rigel pointed out, the other problem has $1/k$ decay, whereas here we have $1/k^2$.

Comment: Sorry, I was watching again your previous post and I am not fully convinced anymore by the explanation I was giving in the previous comments. Do you remember what $\Delta$ t you used in the second set of plots in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/43433/can-this-finite-difference-dispersion-be-eliminated-somehow ?  (in the first set it was approx 1/1000, right?). Also, what is the value of $v_0$ here? Lastly, can you also add the plot of the difference between the numerical and analytical solution? This would allow better assess what kind of numerical errors you have here. Thanks!

Comment: In the previous question, $t_{max}$ was $2.5$ and $x_{max}$ was $1$. Also, $nt$ was $1250$ and $nx$ was $500$. So $\Delta t$ was $0.0020$ and so was $\Delta x$. This is for the second set of plots. For the first set of plots, $\Delta t$ was $9.6154e-04$ and $\Delta x$ was $0.0017$. Here $v_0$ is $0.5$. However, I doubt that the value of $v_0$ is important because the wave function can be divided with it to get almost the same set of equations. The difference is the new function would be equal to $1$ at $x=0, t=0$. I will add the plot :D

Comment: This may be one of those scenarios where the dispersion term in the finite difference error term cancels out if $\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}=1$ and we get higher order convergence than expected

Comment: @NikolaRistic are you sure about those numbers? Apologies if I ask again, I'm telling you why I doubt. In your previous post, the first plot should have $\Delta x = 1/500 \neq 0.0017$. Also, it looking at the plot, it seems that the second one has much denser x points. My hypothesis is that you increased the x points in the second plot ant kept the same $\Delta t$. If this is correct, then I believe I found another issue in your previous post. But we can have a separate chat about that, in case you are still interested in that question.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake and you are correct. The spatial step really is 0.002. Dont know how I got the 0.0017. I also agree with your answer. There is simply a big difference between a nonsmooth continuous functioan and a discontinuous one. Im glad the FDM can also be used for nonsmooth functions sometimes. Thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the plots of the errors, it seems that there is not much difference between the oscillations that you have in this case with respect to those that you had in your previous post ([Can this finite difference dispersion be eliminated somehow?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/43433/can-this-finite-difference-dispersion-be-eliminated-somehow)).
In your previous post the peak of the oscillations was approximately as high as $1/3$ of the jump that you have in your solution. Here I see approximately the same.

Let's pick the plots at $t=0.4$ for the case where $\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x } \neq 1$: the oscillation peaks at $0.5$E-3 and the $\Delta u$ is approximately $0.016$ in the vicinity of the peak (you have 12 points ranging from $u=0.2$ to $u=0$). The ratio $0.005 / 0.016$ is approximately $1/3$.

Long story short: your solution here is continuous and you cannot notice the effect of the dispersive properties of your FD method, unless you look very closely.